# Android return value from AccessibilityService

Tags: java, android, service, accessibilityservice

i have this AccessibilityService class for the USSD

```
public class USSDService extends AccessibilityService {
    public static String TAG = "USSDService";

    @Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onAccessibilityEvent");
        String text = event.getText().toString();

        if (event.getClassName().equals("android.app.AlertDialog")) {
            performGlobalAction(GLOBAL_ACTION_BACK);
            Log.d(TAG, text);
            Intent intent = new Intent("com.times.ussd.action.REFRESH");
            intent.putExtra("message", text);//this is the value that i want to return to MainActivity
            Toast.makeText  (this,text,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInterrupt() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onServiceConnected() {
        super.onServiceConnected();
        Log.d(TAG, "onServiceConnected");
        AccessibilityServiceInfo info = new AccessibilityServiceInfo();
        info.flags = AccessibilityServiceInfo.DEFAULT;
        info.packageNames = new String[]{"com.android.phone"};
        info.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED;
        info.feedbackType = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FEEDBACK_GENERIC;
        setServiceInfo(info);
    }}
```

and i invoke in main activity like this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ////////////////USSD////////////////////
    Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, USSDService.class);
    startService(mIntent);
}
```

and this is a function that dial ussd

```
private void dailNumber(String code) {
    String ussdCode = "*" + code + Uri.encode("#");
    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL)
        .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + ussdCode));
    callIntent.putExtra("simSlot", 0);
    startActivity(callIntent);
}
```

when i call this function by clicking a button, every thing is ok and the response of ussd call show in Toast as i code it in function onAccessibilityEvent 
what i want is return the response value to MainActivity

Answer (score 0):

Accessibility services cannot be started in the manner you are attempting to start them. They can only be managed from the Accessibility Settings menu.  This is for good reason. Accessibility services can read screen contents. OH, you downloaded my app, that's nice. NOW I'm going to launch an Accessibility Service that watches all of your screen content for things that look like Credit Card numbers.

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, USSDService.class);
startService(mIntent);
```

The lines of code above ARE NOT accomplishing what you think they are. The accessibility service will launch (call your service's onCreate), but it will launch in a functionally limited state that does not allow it to bind to applications and the Android Operating System in the way an Accessibility Service normally would.

Once properly configured, go to Settings -> Accessibility and find your service listed next to TalkBack. Then turn it on. Once you do this, in order to communicate between your two processes you're going to need some type of interprocess communication mechanism.  For simple communication you can consider using SharePreferences. Otherwise, you're probably going to have to look into BroadCastReceivers.

See how far that gets you, and ask another question if you need!

Comment: my code is work but i need to return value to MainActivity, i need a code

Comment: Just because your code runs, does not mean it "works". You CANNOT start accessibility services in this way, period. Until that issue is fixed, this discussion is purely academic, because functionality in this case is ambiguous, unsupported, fragile, and any other number of bad terms you can apply to fundamentally broken code.

Comment: can you see my question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45758930/android-use-broadcast-receivers-to-send-value)