# Android use Broadcast Receivers to send value

Tags: java, android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I have this AccessibilityService class:

```
public class USSDService extends AccessibilityService {
public static String TAG = "USSDService";
public String responsee="";
@Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onAccessibilityEvent");
    String text = event.getText().toString();

    if (event.getClassName().equals("android.app.AlertDialog")) {
        performGlobalAction(GLOBAL_ACTION_BACK);
        Log.d(TAG, text);
        Intent intent = new Intent("message");
        intent.putExtra("value", text);
        Toast.makeText  (this,text,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        this.sendBroadcast(intent);// write a broad cast receiver and call sendbroadcast() from here, if you want to parse the message for balance, date
    }

}

@Override
public void onInterrupt() {
}

@Override
protected void onServiceConnected() {
    super.onServiceConnected();
    Log.d(TAG, "onServiceConnected");
    AccessibilityServiceInfo info = new AccessibilityServiceInfo();
    info.flags = AccessibilityServiceInfo.DEFAULT;
    info.packageNames = new String[]{"com.android.phone"};
    info.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED;
    info.feedbackType = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FEEDBACK_GENERIC;
    setServiceInfo(info);
}}
```

As you can see in the method `onAccessibilityEvent`, I send intent by using the method `sendBroadcast`.

In MainActivity I use BroadcastReceiver to receive the value like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private BroadcastReceiver bReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //put here whaterver you want your activity to do with the intent received
        Log.i("onReceive",intent.getStringExtra("value") );
    }
};

protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    Log.i("onResume", "22222");
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(bReceiver, new IntentFilter("message"));
}

protected void onPause (){
    super.onPause();
    Log.i("onPause", "11111");

    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(bReceiver);
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);}}
```

My App works fine when I call ussd the method `onAccessibilityEvent` is work and the value show in Toast, but the method `onReceive` did not work and I don't know where the problem is. Please help me.

Comment: You may need to change somethingin that and add intentfilter so it makes sure that it calls the same function that you need

Comment: I think it's because you're sending a global Broadcast with `this.sendBroadcast(intent)` then registering your receiver locally. Try `LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);` instead.

Comment: i tried this but it did not work

Comment: @Brian i dont understand what you mean

Comment: Please ignore my last comment. Is there an action set for your receiver in your manifest?

Comment: no there isn't, how can i do it?

Comment: try the code below, replacing the action string with your own app's package name

Comment: You should bring your code down to be the minimal functional example that demonstrates your issue. There is a lot of unnecessary stuff in here making it difficult to read.

Answer (score 1):

An AccessibilityService that has been launched properly and your Activity are going to exist in separate processes. This is by definition. Assuming that you have launched your AccessibilityService properly, the following is what you want.

```
public class USSDService extends AccessibilityService {

    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(getPackageName() + "ACTION_ID");
        intent.putExtra("extra_id", "value");

        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}
```

You would then register for this broadcast in your Activity like so:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();

        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Log.d("Broadcast", intent.getExtras().getString("extra_id"));
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(getPackageName() + "ACTION_ID"));
    }
}
```

Important part here is A: your intent filter is tied to your package name, and that "ACTION_ID" is always the same string. Ultimately this is probably best accomplished by a public static final string in either your Activity class or your service class... or in some other class abstracting away this layer of communication.